# Is there a 'willSet' & 'didSet' I can intercept for UIScrollview.contentOffset?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a situation where I need to gracefully move a frame when the `contentOffset.y` is a negative value.

The problem is I don't want to get the `contentOffset` call **AFTER** the content has already been dropped below 0.

Is there a `willSet` call where I can intercept it before the `UIScrollView` offsets its content?

Comment: In Objective-C, you can register for notifications on the scroll view's bounds changing. I don't know much about using that in Swift, though.

Comment: You mean as a delegate call?

Comment: No, I mean `NSNotificationCenter`.

Comment: Either answers work I can move between them unless theres something specific that only one can do and not the other

Comment: If it's a "frame" maybe display it over the scroll view instead of in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a willSet pretty easily in swift.  Just subclass UIScrollView and only override that, like so.  Obviously you'll wanna do something besides println, but I verified this definitely fires before the didScroll delegate does.  I don't know that it will resolve your animation issue, but this is what you asked for.

```
import UIKit

class MyScrollView: UIScrollView {

    override var contentOffset: CGPoint { willSet { println("old value \(newValue)") } }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems, this works:

```
class MyScrollView: UIScrollView {
    override var contentOffset:CGPoint {
        willSet {
            println("newOffset: \(newValue)")
        }
    }
}
```

In your subclass of `UIScrollView`, just override the `willSet` of `contentOffset` . It seems that is called before `layoutSubviews()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the delegate methods `scrollViewDidScroll` or `scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating`  and intercept the`contentOffset.y`. I hope this help you.

Comment: `didScroll` is going to be your best bet, it will be continuously invoked as the view is scrolled, so moving your frame (with either no or a *very* short animation) should be smooth.

Comment: That is what I do, but it's choppy, and hence why I was looking to intercept the willSet call if possible